# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Tengo echa una aplicación web en .net core, la aplicación en el entorno de desarrollo funciona correctamente, pero al ser publicada en el entorno productivo, lanza *ServerName no puede procesar esta solicitud en este momento. HTTP ERROR 500*, probé entrar con en el navegador del servidor donde esta alojada de forma productiva y arroja el mismo error, revisando Event Viewer lanza este error de *.NET Runtime*

```
Exception: 
System.InvalidOperationException: The exception handler configured on ExceptionHandlerOptions produced a 404 status response. This InvalidOperationException containing the original exception was thrown since this is often due to a misconfigured ExceptionHandlingPath. If the exception handler is expected to return 404 status responses then set AllowStatusCode404Response to true.
 ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
   at Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<Main>$>b__1(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in D:\YMM Projects\YMMScrapSystem\YMMScrapSystem\Program.cs:line 25
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.CreateDbContextOptions[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
```

El parametro `connectionString` esta declarado de esta forma:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Connectionstrings": 
  {
    "ScrapContext": "Server=11.209.122.94;Database=YMM_ScrapSystem;User ID=admin;Password=abc367/+_;"
  }
}
```

Comment: Cuando publicas se generan 2 archivos json, uno de desarrollo y otro de producción, verificaste que en ambos archivos estuviera el connectionstring??? Por otro lado, he leído de personas que tienen problemas cuando la aplicación se encuentra en una subcarpera y lo que hace es poner el json en la raíz

Comment: @Yussef tenias razón con respecto al json, en el productivo no tenia ni la mitad del contenido del de desarrollo, de momento copie el contenido, pero validare porque sucedió esto.

Answer (score 0):

El contenido de los archivos json appsettings y appsettings.Development no era el mismo, appsettings.Development contenía dentro la cadena de conexión, mientras que appsettings no, copie el contenido del json de desarrollo al productivo y funciono con normalidad.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]